# visual studio 2017 - disable auto inject of "import"

Tags: javascript, import, visual-studio-2017

This is not a question about actual programming per say, but it is very well related, so I'm posting it here...

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 on a local JS code. Obviously, I have a few extensions installed and basically, everything is working fine.

However, whenever I add certain pieces of code to my file, there's an automatic inject of "dependency" code to the file.

For example, if I add "clearTimeout..." to my code, immediately, the following line will be added at the top of the file:

```
import { clearTimeout } from "timers";
```

This will occur also for things like "setTimeout" and so on.

I don't need that to happen and I can't find how to disable this behavior.